# how to call map in test class

Tags: unit-test

```
Map<String, Mapping__c> mapDiscField_Object{get{
        Map<String, Mapping__c> mField_Object = new Map<String, ping__c>();
        for(ping__c obj pingHandler.createList()) { 
            if(obj.Objtme__c == 'Contact') {
                mld_Object.put(obj.Ded__c, obj);
            } 
        }
        return mField_Object;
    }set;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to access the data in the map from test class? If yes, here is the answer.

```
    Classname instancevar = new classname();

    instancevar.mapName - This will return your map data inside test method.
```

Answer (score 2):

I dont think you have to do anything different to cover maps in your test code.

The only thing that you should take care is that you prepare the data in such a way that your Maps will be having values.So that all the conditions in your code are satisfied.